# Exchange Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange

trying to create script to delete exchange 2010 mailbox messages.

creating input file in csv format with three headers.

Recipients Subject Sender

with these values:

```
line1: user1@campus.edu,Somesubject,sender@domain.com  
line2: "user2@campus.edu,user3@campus.edu",Somesubject,sender@domain.com
```

created this powershell script:

```
$list = Import-Csv "input.csv"
Foreach ($entry in $list)
{
    If ($entry.Recipients.Contains(","))
    {
        $recipients = $entry.Recipients.Split(",")
        ForEach($recipient in $recipients)
        {
            $search = "Subject:`"" + $entry.Subject + "`" And From:`"" + $entry.Sender + "`" And Sent:5/27/2016"
            Write-Host $search
            Search-Mailbox -identity $Recipients -SearchQuery $search -TargetMailbox "my_mailbox" -TargetFolder "05272016" -LogLevel Full -deletecontent
        }
    }
    Else    
    {
        $search = "Subject:`"" + $entry.Subject + "`" And From:`"" + $entry.Sender + "`" And Sent:5/27/2016"
        Write-Host $search
        Search-Mailbox -identity $entry.Recipients -SearchQuery $search -TargetMailbox "my_mailbox" -TargetFolder "05272016" -LogLevel Full -deletecontent
    }

}
```

It works with single recipients but not multiple recipients. Any ideas how to split multiple recipients.

Comment: found my problem, changed Search-Mailbox -identity $Recipients  to $Recipient in first portion. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

found my problem, changed Search-Mailbox -identity $Recipients to $Recipient in first portion. Thanks for your consideration.